# Select all data of datatable with serverside pagination Jquery Datatable

Tags: jquery, datatable, datatables

I want to select all data of all pages with checkbox when I click on selectAll button. I am using, Zend framework 1 and DataTables 1.10.13

```js
$('#exmple').DataTable({
  "ajax": {
    "url": participantListUrl,
    "type": "POST",
    data: function(d) {}
  },
  stateSave: true,
  "serverSide": true,
  "processing": true,
  "responsive": true,
  "columnDefs": [{
    "targets": 'no-sort',
    "orderable": false,
  }],
  "order": [
    [1, 'desc']
  ],
  "fnDrawCallback": function(oSettings) {
    $(".chkbox").on('click', function() {
      checkBoxSelect();
    });
    $('#selectAll').removeAttr('checked');
  },
  "rowCallback": function(row, data) {
    selected = [];
  },
  "drawCallback": function(settings) {
    manageOptions('');
  },
});
```

Comment: The main point of using server-side processing with DataTables is because you want to avoid downloading every row to the browser (due to the large volume). Therefore you will _typically_ only have one page of data stored in the browser at a time. So, there is no way to "select all data of all pages" using DataTables, assuming a sensible implementation of server-side processing. To put it another way: If your DataTable contained all your data, there would be no point in using `"serverSide": true`.

Comment: Could you find a soliution Lalji ? I am facing a similar issue. I am looking to select. all after filtering.

Comment: If you really want to use DataTables with server-side processing _and_ still be able to export the entire data set to a file, then you can use the solution provided [in this DataTables forum discussion](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/59216/customizing-the-data-from-export-buttons#latest). The code provided there does work (I tested it). But really, I would be very hesitant to go this way for the reasons I give above. If you have so much data that you _need to use_ server-side processing, then you _should_ also use a server-side export-to-file process (IMHO). But it's up to you.